# Storing Result of Command line for further data analysis in Python

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis

I am going to build a script that will extract certain features of PDF file. The output of my extraction for each file is going to be something like:

```
 obj                    8
 endobj                 8
 stream                 1
 endstream              1
 xref                   1
 trailer                1
 startxref              1
 /Page                  1
 /Encrypt               0
```

Now I need to create a data set of this result for over thousand files. 
My final dataset should store the numeric value for each entity here.
Eg:

```
obj: 8,6,5,2,8,9
endobj:8,5,4,1,1,2,3
...
..
...
```

Once I have this data, I plan to run statistics like what is the average value for Obj etc. Keeping these things in mind, what should be the most ideal way of approaching this. 
I was planning to create a table where the entity will become the row and the values as columns. 
I also came across `numpy` as my work is mainly on data analysis, but I am not sure if it fits in this situation. 
Please share your suggestions.

Comment: Do you plan to use multidimensional arrays, and linear algebra? If not, `numpy` probably isn't going to be particularly useful. `pandas` may be useful. Or maybe you might just need a `dict`. However, this question seems too broad. \

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using python `dict`. Worked perfectly for me.